# Count the total number of positive and negative returns in a data set

Tags: r

I am trying to find the total days of positive and negative returns for a given data set.
I tried using the difference function to find the returns for the company followed by subset function and then the count function. However it does not give me the desired output. Could you please help?

Working:

```
Date          AMZN          GOOG       WFM          MSFT
1/2/2016    574.809998      752      29.959999    54.709999
2/2/2016    552.099976  764.650024   28.93        53
3/2/2016    531.070007  726.950012   28.639999    52.16
4/2/2016    536.26001   708.01001    29.200001    52
5/2/2016    502.130005  683.570007   29.190001    50.16
8/2/2016    488.100006  682.73999    29.379999    49.41
9/2/2016    482.070007  678.109985   29.059999    49.279999
10/2/2016   490.480011  684.119995   28.870001    49.709999
11/2/2016   503.820007  683.109985   28.93        49.689999
12/2/2016   507.079987  682.400024   30.65        50.5
16/02/2016  521.099976  691          30.9        51.09
17/02/2016  534.099976  708.400024   31.76       52.419998
18/02/2016  525         697.349976   31.389999   52.189999
19/02/2016  534.900024  700.909973   31.389999   51.82
22/02/2016  559.5       706.460022   30.66       52.650002
```

I broke down the returns of Amazon alone to uderstand how it can be done and tried the following:

```
m<-diff(mydf$AMZN)/mydf$AMZN[-length(mydf$AMZN)]
m
n<-subset(m,m<0)
c(n)
```

The count function is what I am using to obtain the number of days. However, it gives me the error. Is that the right way to go about it? The output has to be 113 days the returns for Amazon were negative.

Need to do this for the entire data set. I.e. Find the total number of days with positive and negative returns.

Comment: Why should the output be 113 days for Amazon? There are only 15 days of data..

Comment: My bad, the output of 113 days for the entire data set that I have. The data posted here is only partial. The entire data set solution I was talking about. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returns are positive, when the price at day `T` is higher than in day `T-1`, right? That also implies, that you cannot know whether on day1, the returns were positive or negative, because a comparison day is missing.

Based on your description, the following should give you what you're looking for:

```
daily_return <- diff(df$AMZN)

nr_pos <- sum( daily_return > 0)   # 8
nr_neg <- sum( daily_return < 0)   # 6
```

Comment: Thanks. So if we apply to the entire dataset , can we use the below:               m<-cbind(mydf[-1,1],apply(mydf[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1)))*100
m
n<-subset(m,m<0)
n
sum(n<0)

Comment: Also, can we plot the daily returns in R? I want to assign the daily returns of each company on the x,y axis. How do we do that?